# Using PHP Array for javascript select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I mixed the code that I have and from the Stackoverflow related in using select option.

The code  has javascript and php & I included the link to the plugins just for details.

So I used php arrays for the select option. I am trying to **populate the 2nd** selection option which is for the select city.

> I need to use PHP array because of timezone purposes

[image]

> Problem: Unable to populate the second option(s)

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json_parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json_parse_state.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cycle.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 
<?php $myvalues = array(
"Japan (日本)"=>"JP",
"Albania (Shqipëri"=>"AL",
"Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)"=>"DZ",
"American Samoa"=>"AS",
"Andorra"=>"AD",
"Angola"=>"AO",
"Anguilla"=>"AI",
"Antarctica"=>"AQ",); ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($myvalues ); ?>;
        for (var i = 0; i < jqueryarray.length; i++) 
  {
            console.log(jqueryarray[i]);
        };
  
  $("#type").change
  (function (){
        var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "Japan (日本)"=>"JP",) 
  {
            $("#ddlViewBy").html("<select id=\"jap\"><option value=\"9\">Fukuoka </option><option value=\"9\">Hamamatsu</option><option value=\"9\">Himeji</option><option value=\"9\">Hiroshima</option><option value=\"9\">Kagoshima</option><option value=\"9\">Kawasaki</option><option value=\"9\">Kitakyushu</option><option value=\"9\">Kobe</option><option value=\"9\">Kumamoto</option><option value=\"9\">Kyoto</option><option value=\"9\">Matsuyama</option><option value=\"9\">Nagoya</option><option value=\"9\">Niigata</option><option value=\"9\">Osaka</option><option value=\"9\">Sagamihara</option><option value=\"9\">Sapporo</option> <option value=\"9\">Shizuoka</option><option value=\"9\">Tokyo</option><option value=\"9\">Utsunomiya</option><option value=\"9\">Yokohama</option></select>");
  }  
  else if (val =="Andorra")
  {
      $("#ddlViewBy").html("<select id=\"pin\"><option value=\"8\">light</option><option value=\"8\">Saint</option><option value=\"8\">grin</option><option value=\"8\">cake</option></select>");
  
  }
});

</script>
<select id ="type">
<option value="">-----------------</option>
 
<?php
foreach($myvalues as $key => $value):
echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
endforeach;
?>
</select>
 <select id="ddlViewBy">
   <option value="">select city</script></option> 
 </select> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it OK if the code is changed (the majority of it)?

Comment: Try changing `if(val == "Japan (日本)"=>"JP",)` to just `if(val == "Japan (日本)")`. And then follow Azamantes' answer.

Comment: @EdvinTenovim sure ! no problem it will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put select inside another select.

```
$("#ddlViewBy").html("<select id=\"pin\"><option value=\"8\">light</option><option value=\"8\">Saint</option><option value=\"8\">grin</option><option value=\"8\">cake</option></select>");
```

Try to put just the options, without  tags. That should work for the javascript part.

This is clearly not javascript. I don't know what it is:

```
if (val == "Japan (日本)"=>"JP",); // you are trying to compare javascript with PHP style array element.
```

Javascript is executed in the browser and PHP is executed on the server, they cannot run at the same time on your webpage. PHP is executed before your webpage even gets to the browser via network. That might clear things up a little bit and help you avoid confusing these two.

You can create an map-like object and then do something like:

```
if(val === mapObject['JP']) // or something similar
```

You can just create an array of strings and then concatenate them into the big HTML if you really need to do it this way (changing innerHTML of the DOM element).

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I am trying to do with javascript and php array. I used it for the timezone .

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions.